# Extending a @Entity Anotated Class with Child class having save(this) method

Tags: java, database, hibernate, persistence

I dont know if Hibernate can be Implemented this way..........For example, I have the class below............

```
@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable{

  private String name;
  private int age;
  private String gender;
  ........
  ........Getters and setters also
}
```

Can I extend this class like so in order to save an employee object in the database

```
public class EmployeeDataObject extends Employee{
  public boolean save()
  {
       SessionFactory sessionFac = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFac.openSession();
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(this);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
        session.close();
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: do you mean whether it can be done technically, or whether it is a good solution?

Comment: @kostja Both.............@jb-nizet i just want some explanation on the technical point of view............>>Thanks for the prompt response by the way

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be done technically. Looks like you would like to implement some sort of [Active Record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern). I think that a good, JPA-compliant implementation of Active Record would be wonderful.

There are a couple of projects which try to achieve that. You may want to take a look at some of them:

- [hiverecord](https://code.google.com/p/hiverecord/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/googlecode/hiverecord/HiveRecord.java) - it takes a different inheritance approach (entities derive from a DAO-like abstract class). However the available implementation is quite basic and the project looks abandoned.
- [ActiveJDBC](https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc) - a more complete implementation of Active Record, however not at all JPA-compliant.

I am not sure how far you can take the idea compared to the [ruby implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activerecord). The static typing and compile-time generics of Java will probably get in your way rather sooner than later, but godspeed :)